# Scrolling specific size image in any direction

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

Hi, I have an image called id="design" with this proportions: 5500px X 3800px.

I would like to have centered the design and full screen on my computer or phone browser, and scroll in any direction to see the entire design. Should I get this done with Javascript? thanks

Comment: I would just say Yes but I think its not what you really want `-`

Comment: @GuilhermeSilva please explain me a bit more why you're saying that? thanks!

Comment: I was replying this question:

_Should I get this done with Javascript? _

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add all the code i write down here to a css file and then 
link it to the website html that you want to become responsive.. 
:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { /*StyleHere{}*/

}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {  
/*StyleHere{}*/
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { 
/*StyleHere{}*/
 }

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {  
/*StyleHere{}*/
}


@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {  
/*StyleHere{}*/
 }


@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1){
/*StyleHere{}*/
}


@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  {  
/*StyleHere{}*/
}


@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { 
/*StyleHere{}*/
 }

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  { 
/*StyleHere{}*/
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  {  
/*StyleHere{}*/
}


@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  { 
/*StyleHere{}*/
 }

Screen Width = 768px (CSS Pixels)
Screen Height = 1024px (CSS Pixels)

Screen Width = 768px (Actual Pixels)
Screen Height = 1024px (Actual Pixels)

Device-pixel-ratio: 1

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) {  
/*StyleHere{}*/
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/*StyleHere{}*/
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { 
/*StyleHere{}*/
 }

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) {  
/*StyleHere{}*/
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/*StyleHere{}*/
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { 
/*StyleHere{}*/
 }

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) {  
/*StyleHere{}*/
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { 
/*StyleHere{}*/
}


@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {  
/*StyleHere{}*/
 }


@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) { 
/*StyleHere{}*/
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { 
/*StyleHere{}*/
}

@media only screen /*iphone5*/
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { 
/*StyleHere{}*/
}



@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 
/*StyleHere{}*/
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 604px) and (max-device-width : 966px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/*StyleHere{}*/
}


/* Google Nexus 7 2 (portrait and landscape) */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 600px) and (max-device-width : 960px) {
/*StyleHere{}*/
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1200px)
    and (max-device-width: 1600px)
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
/*StyleHere{}*/
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1200px)
    and (max-device-width: 1920px)
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
/*StyleHere{}*/
}


@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1600px)
    and (max-device-width: 2560px)
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
    /*StyleHere{}*/
}
```

Comment: Hi @omer malka, thanks but my idea is not to make the site responsive, is to have a huge design and allow people to scroll through the entire design, for example : www.flightradar24.com

Answer (score 0):

I have recently see a library which can help you a lot. It's called Intense-Images.

The github project is here: https://github.com/tholman/intense-images

A demo using some big images is here: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?51_0C5cn

Html:

```
<img src="./img/awesome-source.jpg" class="intense" data-title="My beach adventure" data-caption="Thanks Sam, for the great picture"/>
```

Js: (include intense.js and jQuery too)

```
window.onload = function() {
    // Intensify all images with the 'intense' classname.
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll( '.intense' );
    Intense( elements );
}
```

And some css:

```
.intense {
    cursor: url('./you-image-directory/plus_cursor.png') 25 25, auto;
}
```

Please note that you cannot scroll in all directions, but there probably will be some work related in the future: https://github.com/tholman/intense-images/issues/31

Hope that helped a little for your start. Of course you can always extend the plugin to achieve that.